# change labelText direction to RTL in InputDecoration() flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

just I want to change direction of `labelText` to RTL in below code:

```
 new TextField(
     textAlign: TextAlign.right,
     controller: _textEdittingControler_bookName,
     autofocus: true,
     decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "افزودن کتاب",
                hintText: "نام کتاب را وارد کنید"
                ),
     )
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Simply use Directionality:

```
new Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: TextField(
     textAlign: TextAlign.right,
     controller: _textEdittingControler_bookName,
     autofocus: true,
     decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "افزودن کتاب",
                hintText: "نام کتاب را وارد کنید"
                ),
     )
```

[Directionality's docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html)

Comment: Best answer and working perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Can be used ***`textAlign`***

```
            TextFormField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'ادخل تفاصيل الكتابة الخاصة بك',
              ),
```